# Convertir valores ajustados entre 0 y 1 a valores entre 1 y 52 con distribución uniforme discreta en Python

Tags: python

Como contexto, decir que estoy calculando las probabilidades de que salgan pares, tercias en X cantidad de manos, y en X cantidad de intentos, hasta ahora esto lo hago con `random.sample`, pero necesito usar los métodos de generación de números aleatorios que yo hice, el problema es que estos me devuelven valores de 0 a 1.

Ahora, trato de ver si hay una función que ya lo haga en Python, según tengo entendido si, pero no la he encontrado, o alguna solución diferente es aceptada igualmente, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Basta con ampliar mediante multiplicación y desplazamiento,  luego haces truncado de los decimales. Si deseas de 1 a 52 inclusive y tu método devuelve de 0 a 1 inclusive, puedes multiplicar por 51 directamente y al resultado sumarle 1, luego usar `floor`. En caso que sea un rango abierto en 1, multiplicas por 52, sumas 1 e igualmente usas `floor`. Si no es eso lo que buscas, entonces no entiendo. Saludos

Comment: Si necesitas valores entre 1-52 y random the da valores normalizados entre 0.0 y 1.0 solo multiplica por 52 y redondeas el valor, si es que entendi bien tu pregunta

Comment: Otra opción es usar directamente `randint(start, end)` del módulo `random`. De esta forma puedes obtener un valor entero *pseudoaleatorio* en el rango que especifiques usando `start` y `end`. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios, he encontrado la solución en un libro que se llama Simulación y Análisis de Sistemas con ProModel 2a. Ed.
Adjunto la solución, y agradezco su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

las distribuciones uniformes entre dos pares de numeros pueden ser generadas con el metodo random.uniform.

```
import random

distribution = round(random.uniform(1, 52))
```